# Angular: Adding value to array of another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components, onclick of button of 1st component the value (any string) should be added to the array of the 2nd component. How can i achieve this? I work on angular 4.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
newMessage() {
    console.log("button clicked");
  }
```

Comment: What's the relationship between these components? Parent-child? Siblings?

Comment: Use a service (based on observables) to comlunicate between the 2 components if they are not parent/child, otherwise use Input/Output

Comment: is it parent /child relationship

Comment: Have a look at the official docs about it: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: use  [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 1):

You are primarily looking to communicate between two components,

You can use a service with Array. A service in Angular is a singleton, meaning it is managed as a single instance. So if each of the components access the service, they will access the same shared data.

```
export class cartService{
    prod :any = [];        
    UpdateArray (newObject: any) {
        this.prod.push(newObject);         
    }
}
```

In your component you can do this,

```
  this._cartService.UpdateArray(this.prod);
```

any can be replaced with your object type